# Анимация - изменение opacity при клике

Tags: javascript, html

как сделать чтобы при нажатии на любую из них квадрат начинает плавно моргать меняя opacity?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```js
var cols = prompt('Введите количество строк', '');
var rows = prompt('Введите количество столбцов', '');
cols = parseInt(cols);
rows = parseInt(rows);
document.write('<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="1000px" height="600px">');
var color;

function getColor() {

  var min = 1,
    max = 2;
  var colorNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (max) + min),
    color;
  if (colorNum == 1) {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  if (colorNum == 2) {
    color = 'green';
  }
  if (colorNum == 3) {
    color = 'red';
  }
  console.log(colorNum);
  return color;

}
for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
    document.write('<td style="background-color:' + getColor() + '"></td>');
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write('</table>');
```

```css
table {
margin: 0 auto
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример использования JS && CSS

```js
var cols = prompt('Введите количество строк', '');
var rows = prompt('Введите количество столбцов', '');
cols = parseInt(cols);
rows = parseInt(rows);

var table = document.createElement("table");
table.border = 1;
table.cellPadding = 2
table.cellSpacing = 0
table.width = "1000px"
table.style.width = "1000px"
table.height = "600px"
table.style.height = "600px"

document.body.appendChild(table);
var color;


function blink(){
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for( var i in tds ){
    tds[i].className = "";
  }
  this.className = "blink";
}

function getColor() {

  var min = 1,
    max = 2;
  var colorNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (max) + min),
    color;
  if (colorNum == 1) {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  if (colorNum == 2) {
    color = 'green';
  }
  if (colorNum == 3) {
    color = 'red';
  }
  console.log(colorNum);
  return color;

}
for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
 var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  table.appendChild(tr);
  
  for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
    var tdElement = document.createElement("td");
        tdElement.addEventListener("click", blink);
        tdElement.style.backgroundColor = getColor() 
    tr.appendChild( tdElement );
  }
}
```

```css
table {
margin: 0 auto
}

.blink {
  animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

Comment: а где вызывается `blink`?

Comment: @Grundy tdElement.addEventListener("click", blink);

Comment: ага, не заметил эту строчку

Comment: @ANTON уточните что именно не понятно.

Comment: @xAqweRx tds[i].className = ""  вот это строка если возможно объясните

Comment: @ANTON, сброс всех установленных классов

Comment: @Grundy понял спасибо

Comment: @xAqweRx спасибо

Answer (score 0):

вот пример как это можно сделать с помощю css `animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out;`.можно просто добавить это свойство и он елемент который вы укажите будем мигать. И еще нужно добавить потом

```
@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

Comment: нужно на javascript

Comment: @Tigo, почему вы думаете, что нужно на яваскрипте? если на нем вы все равно будете менять те же css свойства - какая разница?

Comment: @Grundy задача такова чтобы создать на javascript-e а не на css

Comment: @ANTON ,лабораторка? :-)

Comment: @Grundy нет задача для себя,долго голову морочил))

Comment: @Grundy на экзамен готовлюсь еще может быть такое будет :-)